# Can't access my service with NginxProxyManager web UI

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an Ubuntu server running NginxProxyManager (NPM) in a docker container and want to access my app running in a separate docker container listening on port 3000.

So the NPM should forward [www.my-app.com](http://www.my-app.com) to my-app:3000, but somehow I couldn't manage to get this working using the NPM's webUI.
The image below is how I thought to realise the forwarding:
[image]

This is what I want to achieve with NPM:
[image]

NPM looks easy to use, but when using with docker containers you're left on your own imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have pretty much the same setup.

You dont use localhost but make sure the two containers are on the same docker network, then use the container name instead of localhost.

To make sure they are on the same network you can make a custom network and attach them both. I would use bridge mode when making the new network but you can make networks that are not available from the outside which is neat.

Also to make sure they are both connected to anything you can do `docker exec -it containername /bin/bash`. If you have ping installed in the container, use ping google.com to see if dns resolves correctly. You can also ping ips 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8 to see if internet connection works at all.

If you get an error that bash is unknown, you can try /bin/sh

Good luck.

Comment: This helped me a lot. I created a bridge network with docker cli, than I defined the network in each docker-compose.yml and added each container_name. I than used container name as forward host name. Furthermore I also "expose"ed port instead of mapping the internal port to the host port.

Comment: Great to hear it! Feel free to accept my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

In proxy rather than writing localhost give the container IP Address of the application.

To view the IP Address run the below command replace

```
docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_id
```

and make sure that the app is running (command: `docker ps`)

Comment: This helped me to look more deeply on interconnection between docker containers.